# Matlab - Voting matrix

Tags: matlab

Lets say that I have a number of `n` matrices with the same size (`p x q` elements). Can you obtain a matrix contains the elements with the highest frequency on each corresponding position?

For example, let's say that I have `3` matrices with `3 x 3` elements:

```
m1 = [1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 2 0]
m2 = [1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 3 0]
m3 = [1 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 3 0]
```

The resulting matrix should be:

```
 m = [1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 3 0]
```

I have done this by going through each position of my matrices, but in my real case I have `1000 x 1000` and it would take too long. Is there an automated way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you should combine everything into a 3D array; that will be much easier to handle than loads of individually-named 2D arrays.

Once you have done that, you can simply do [`mode(m_everything, 3)`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mode.html).

Comment: This wouldn't solve my case. If on a position I have something like `2 2 3`, the most frequent one will be `2` whereas, max would return me `3`.

Comment: @Simon, user: Sorry my mistake, I misread.  Try `mode` instead!